# CSS style priority confusion

Tags: css, html, angular, web-frontend

**CSS**

```
.wrapper > * {
    background: deepskyblue;
}

.item {
    background: deeppink;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    Test
  </div>
</div>
```

Above is my CSS class and HTML. So since I have gave style for .item class below the wrapper > * here.

But the item's background is still getting deepskyblue.

Should it be deeppink?

I know I can use !important in .item to get it deeppink but why is this happening in this order is what I want to know.

[image: Screenshot of element inspection in Google Chrome]

Comment: The code you provided renders a `deeppink` background: https://jsfiddle.net/qxvttLyh/

Comment: Check this link http://ccm.net/faq/30797-css-priority-rules-weight and you will know how weights are calculated

Comment: There must be other selectors affecting the values. Try to inspect the result with your browser's developer tools (usually `F12` key), to see what affects it...

Comment: @chazsolo that is even bigger problem then. In jsfiddle it seems to work. I am using it in a component is Angularv4 messing it up? please see the attached screenshot in my question.

Comment: Attribute selectors add specificity to your rule. The `*` selector has no weight at all, but with the addition of `[_ngcontent-c1]` it does, so that's why it's overriding the less-specific rule

Comment: So it's auto-generated by AngularV4 itself anyway to override it?

Comment: Of course, you just need a more specific rule. If you don't want to get rid of `.wrapper[_ngcontent-c1] > *[_ngcontent-c1]` then use `.wrapper[_ngcontent-c1] > .item[_ngcontent-c1]`

Comment: That would be quite an effort since I just shortened the code for brevity. But my actual implementation will have multiple elements with different tags inside main wrapper. Any shortcuts?

Comment: Shortcuts? No... simply _write a more specific rule_ and avoid `!important` unless there is absolutely no other way. I'll put together an answer for you.

Comment: ok sure! Thanks @chazsolo appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand why you aren't seeing the result you want, you need to first understand [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) and what weight selectors have (which is too long of a discussion as an answer to this question).

First, your original set of rules:

```
.wrapper > * { // [0,0,0,1,0]
  background: deepskyblue;
}

.item { // [0,0,0,1,0]
  background: deeppink;
}
```

Both of these rules have a specificity of `[0,0,0,1,0]` because of the single class within each selector. The `*` selector has a weight of 0, so it does not add any weight to the first rule. Since both rules affect the same property on the same element, the rule that comes *last* wins: in this case, `background: deeppink;`

However, your **actual** rules are different:

```
.wrapper[_ngcontent-c1] > *[_ngcontent-c1] { // [0,0,0,3,0]
  background: deepskyblue;
}

.item[_ngcontent-c1] { // [0,0,0,2,0]
  background: deeppink;
}
```

In this case, the first rule wins because it is more specific. Attribute selectors have a weight of `[0,0,0,1,0]`.

To remedy this, you have to make a selector that **equals or surpasses the specificity of the rule to be overridden**.

For example:

```
.wrapper[_ngcontent-c1] > *[_ngcontent-c1] { // [0,0,0,3,0]
  background: deepskyblue;
}

.wrapper[_ngcontent-c1] > .item[_ngcontent-c1] { // [0,0,0,4,0]
  background: deeppink;
}
```

Comment: I read about css specifity rules so it goes like [ Style attribute, ID, Class-Pseudo Class attribute, Element ], so [0,0,0,0] whats why is there 5 0 in your specifity calculation?

Comment: I've seen in the past some examples with 5, denoting a rule with `!important` as adding `[1,0,0,0,0]` to the specificity, just as a visual. I got used to writing it that way.